# Assign list values to dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a list `prices`:

```
prices = [0.9986, 0.8065, -0.1779, 0.8065]
```

and a list of dictionaries `mydicts`:

```
mydicts = [{'name':'Food1'}, {'name':'Food2'}, {'name':'Food3'}, {'name':'Food4'}]
```

Now I need to pass each item of price as value for key `price` in each dictionary, this would be the result:

```
mydicts = [
    {'name':'Food1', 'price':0.9986}, 
    {'name':'Food2', 'price':0.8065}, 
    {'name':'Food3', 'price':-0.1779}, 
    {'name':'Food4', 'price':0.8065}
    ]
```

In order to do this, I'm iterating over the list and the list of dictionaries and asigning each value of the list to the dictionary:

```
for price, dictionary in zip(prices, mydicts):
    dictionary['price'] = price
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, In my case I have to asign lots of values to the list of dictionaries and I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: No, that's pretty much as effective as it gets as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your solution. It's O(n), which is as efficient as possible, and it's simple and short.

Comment: And I understand that If I would need to asign multiple lists instead of only one as in my initial question, it would be more efficient to do it all in one loop, right? In order to still be O(n)

Comment: You're talking about putting more lists like `prices` into the dicts, right? If so, yes, it would be more efficient to do it in one loop than multiple. You would just add them to the `zip`.

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything more efficient than an O(n) approach since you have to touch each index to create each element.